# SP2013: Advanced Search web part returns 0 results

Tags: advanced-search

I am migrating a site collection from SP2010 to SP2013. I need to maintain the search behavior so that I do not use search center approach.

I created a new page `results.aspx` and add two OOB webparts "search results" and "refinement". It works as expected.

SP2013 does not provide OOB advanced search webpart for some reason. Hence I create a search center, export the advanced search webpart and then import to a new page `advanced.aspx`. It looks fine.

However, when I key in a search value in the `advanced.aspx` page, it redirects back to results page as expected. The URL is like `/SitePages/results.aspx?k=ALL(keyword)`. Whatever keyword I used, the advanced webpart just does not work. But the basic search webpart works fine.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I feel like the results.aspx I created cannot read the search term like "ALL", "ANY"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry I just got the answer. It is because I edited the search query on results.aspx. The original query is:

```
{searchboxquery}
```

I changed to:

```
{?{searchboxquery}}
```

It will avoid result.aspx return wildcard result when type in nothing (i.e. /sitespages/results.aspx?k= will return all items within the search result source)

After I remove the questionmark the Advanced search is working now.

Now I have another question... how can I make  /sitespages/results.aspx?k= return nothing?